# How to not require MSBuild package signing (APPX0101)

Tags: msbuild

My app uses MSBuild 12.0 to build our samples in batch. I'm getting error APPX0101 that states, in part, "A signing key is required in order to package this project."

I can specifically filter out this error message by filtering out any error with the APPX0101 substring in it.

My question is, what is the "correct" way to suppress this error message or - better yet - specify that the project being built is not supposed to be signed?

Answer (score 0):

With no details about your project is really difficult to provide an answer...

Have a look at [this answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsapps/en-US/ab3da270-7250-4541-bbb9-da2941f905b3/getting-error-appx0101-during-execution-of-msbuild) on MSDN forums regarding Metro-style applications: they are suggesting to configure a signing certificate to your package.
Assuming it is your case, you can verify the issue by opening your project with a text editor. The following lines should be present and not empty:

```
<PackageCertificateThumbprint><some thumbprint></PackageCertificateThumbprint>
<PackageCertificateKeyFile>FilePicker_TemporaryKey.pfx</PackageCertificateKeyFile>
```

Hope it helps